# Deleting QGraphicsItem with QGraphicsEffect leads to segfault

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

The following program paints a red background. Pressing the left mouse button paints a white rectangle onto it. The rectangle has a child rectangle and a `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect`. (`QGraphicsOpacityEffect` and `QGraphicsColorizeEffect` also lead to the problem, but less frequently.)

Pressing the right mouse button removes the white rectangle.

Sometimes when removing the rectangle it causes a segmentation fault.

This does not happen if the `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` is not applied. It also does not happen when there either is no child item in `MyRect` or the background is ommited.

(When searching for this issue, I found several hints that a segfault like this could be related to changing the `boundingRect()` of an item without calling `prepareGeometryChange()`.)

I am really at a loss here. This is part of a bigger project and I boiled it down to the following example:

Main.cc:

```
#include<QApplication>
#include<QGraphicsView>
#include<QGraphicsScene>
#include<QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include<QGraphicsRectItem>
#include<QGraphicsDropShadowEffect>
#include<QScreen>

class MyRect: public QGraphicsRectItem
{
    public:
    MyRect(QGraphicsItem* parent = nullptr):
        QGraphicsRectItem{QRectF{0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f}, parent}
    {
        setPen(QPen{Qt::white});
        setBrush(QBrush{Qt::white, Qt::SolidPattern});
        my_child_=new QGraphicsRectItem{this};
    }

    private:
    QGraphicsRectItem* my_child_=nullptr;
};

class MyScene: public QGraphicsScene
{
    public:
    MyScene()
    {
        background_=new QGraphicsRectItem{0.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f, 500.0f};
        background_->setPen(QPen{Qt::white});
        background_->setBrush(QBrush{Qt::red, Qt::SolidPattern});
        addItem(background_);
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* me) override
    {
        if (me->button()==Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            if (my_rect_==nullptr)
            {
                my_rect_=new MyRect{};
                shadow_=new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect{};
                shadow_->setBlurRadius(15.0f);
                my_rect_->setGraphicsEffect(shadow_);
                addItem(my_rect_);
                my_rect_->setPos(me->scenePos());
            }
        }
        else if (me->button()==Qt::RightButton)
        {
            if (my_rect_!=nullptr)
            {
                removeItem(my_rect_);
                my_rect_->setGraphicsEffect(0);
                shadow_=nullptr;
                delete my_rect_;
                my_rect_=nullptr;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            QGraphicsScene::mouseReleaseEvent(me);
        }
    }

    private:
    QGraphicsRectItem* background_=nullptr;
    MyRect* my_rect_=nullptr;
    QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* shadow_=nullptr;
};

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication qapp{argc, argv};

    QGraphicsView view;
    MyScene scene;

    QRect rect=QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->geometry();
    scene.setSceneRect(0.0f, 0.0f, rect.width(), rect.height());
    view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    view.setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame);
    view.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt::black, Qt::SolidPattern));
    view.setScene(&scene);
    view.showFullScreen();

    return qapp.exec();
}
```

Compiler call:

```
g++ --std=c++14 -fPIC -Wall -Woverloaded-virtual -Werror -pedantic -g -O0 -fPIC -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -o test Main.cc -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lQt5Widgets
```

Backtrace:

```
#0  0x0000555555a9a840 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff71e017c in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#2  0x00007ffff71e0a3a in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#3  0x00007ffff720289a in QGraphicsView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#4  0x00007ffff6f10278 in QWidget::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#5  0x00007ffff6ff89fe in QFrame::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#6  0x00007ffff72013ab in QGraphicsView::viewportEvent(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#7  0x00007ffff7650701 in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendThroughObjectEventFilters(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007ffff6ec8b65 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#9  0x00007ffff6ed0341 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#10 0x00007ffff76509a0 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#11 0x00007ffff6f08fda in QWidgetPrivate::sendPaintEvent(QRegion const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#12 0x00007ffff6f09646 in QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#13 0x00007ffff6ed8f1e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#14 0x00007ffff6ed9147 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#15 0x00007ffff6ef7f8f in QWidgetPrivate::syncBackingStore() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#16 0x00007ffff6f10348 in QWidget::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#17 0x00007ffff6ff89fe in QFrame::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#18 0x00007ffff7081de3 in QAbstractScrollArea::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#19 0x00007ffff6ec8b8c in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#20 0x00007ffff6ed0341 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#21 0x00007ffff76509a0 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#22 0x00007ffff765312d in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#23 0x00007ffff71d2a22 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#24 0x00007ffff71d8299 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#25 0x00007ffff767d459 in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#26 0x00007ffff71e4e6b in QGraphicsScene::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#27 0x00007ffff6ec8b8c in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#28 0x00007ffff6ed0341 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#29 0x00007ffff76509a0 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#30 0x00007ffff765312d in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#31 0x00007ffff76a4c03 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#32 0x00007ffff446f7f7 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#33 0x00007ffff446fa60 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#34 0x00007ffff446fb0c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#35 0x00007ffff76a500f in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#36 0x00007ffff764e98a in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#37 0x00007ffff76570fc in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#38 0x000055555555768b in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe5b8) at Main.cc:89
```

EDIT: I rewritten the code example for better readability.

Comment: Two questions: (1) why do you do `new QGraphicsRectItem{this}` inside the `MyRect` constructor? I don't think it's a memory leak because of Qt's object hierarchy, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. (2) There's no threading going, right? Updating graphics objects must be done from the main thread.

Comment: Things like that sometimes happen when Qt still has events scheduled for execution on the deleted object - for some reason its deletion doesn't always flush that event queue. As a workaround, you could try instead of deletion do `global_rect->hide(); global_rect->deleteLater(); global_rect = nullptr;` This would let Qt's event loop delete the object itself, when it sees fit.

Comment: @bnaecker @(1): It is required for `MyRect` to have a child to trigger the issue. This is an example, so I just kept it minimal. It's no memory leak since it is parented. @(2) There is `qapp.exec()`, so the main loop is running.

Comment: @Dmitry Unfortunately `QGraphicsRectItem` is just a `QGraphicsItem` and no `QObject`, so there is no `deleteLater()`.

Comment: @Dmitry I just realized, `QGraphicsEffect` is a `QObject`, could the problem be related to that? But how would I deal with this? Calling `QGraphicsItem::setGraphicsEffect(effect)` makes the item take ownership of the effect, `QGraphicsItem::setGraphicsEffect(0)` deletes any present effect. I cannot uncouple the effect from the item to call `deleteLater()` on the effect.

Comment: @TFM, yeah, I didn't realize that `QGraphicsRectItem` is not a `QObject`... Well, you could try something like that: hide the item (but retain the pointer to it in some container), connect the effect's `destroyed` signal to some private slot of the scene (or another object living longer than the item and its effect) where you should be able to finally safely delete the hidden item. Note that for the connection to that signal should be of `QueuedConnection` type in order to know for sure the effect has already been destroyed by the time the slot is called.

Comment: However, that approach involves one more difficulty - how to know which of hidden items to delete on the slot call? I don't have an immediate answer to this. One possibility is to inspect all hidden `QGraphicsItem`s pending deletion and see if their `QGraphicsEffect` is null; if so, it should be safe to delete them.

I must confess I am not really sure the reason for the segfault is the one I'm talking about though. It could be something else. But looking at the top frames of the stack before the crash, it seems that some Qt internals try to work on already deleted `QGraphicsItem` object.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks, I appreciate the effort to find a workaround. But I really need to understand what is going wrong here, especially whether I'm using QT the right way.

Comment: @TFM Why have the scene maintain a pointer to the effect at all? If you add the effect to `my_rect_`, it will be deleted when deleting `my_rect_`. I'm wondering if there's a double-delete happening, especially since `setGraphicsEffect()` applies to all children and you said that the fault only occurs when `my_rect_` has a child.

Comment: @bnaecker You can keep the pointer for reference, you can not keep it. It does not matter. But especially it does not hurt. It's just a pointer.

Comment: @TFM I understand that you can keep a pointer without harm. What I was suggesting was that you may not be able to *delete* the pointed-to object outside of Qt's normal ownership hierarchy without introducing problems. But it appears you've found the solution elsewhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was educated on [on the Qt forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/75510/deleting-qgraphicsitem-with-qgraphicseffect-leads-to-segfault) this is not expected behaviour and might be a bug in Qt.

The best workaround is to call `QGraphicsItem::prepareGeometryChange()` on `my_rect_` *before* removing it from the scene. This might be done be exposing the protected `prepareGeometryChange()` or by calling it inside `~MyRect()` and then simply deleting `my_rect_` *without* calling `QGraphicsScene::removeItem()`. `~QGraphicsItem()`, which of course is called after `~MyRect()`, will automatically remove the item from the scene.

Comment: same issue here, calling `prepareGeometryChange()` in the `QGraphicsItem::ItemSceneChange` case of the `QGraphicsItem::itemChange()` function helped. Thank you.

Comment: BTW: I reported this last year, https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58501